# making a div full width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a div which is at the start of a block. I want it to be in the middle of the page so I have used flexbox and it's working.

I have used this code in CSS.

```css
.elementor-element-acf3e44{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

Now I want this div at full width so I have used this code but when I'm in customize section I see the block taking the full width whenever I go and check the page the block still has the same size and it's not in the middle again. It takes the position it was before. I used this code

```css
.elementor-element-acf3e44 > div:nth-child(1) { 
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

I want to know what the problem is and what caused this conflict.

Comment: hi and Welcome to SO. Please post a working [repro] for debugging details. CSS alone in most cases is useless without the corresponding HTML markup. Most likely, your issue can be solved by using `flex-grow: 1` on your div.

Comment: it works when i'm adding css in additional css but when i publish it and check the website i have the same issue and the div is not in the center. i use wordpress there's no corresponding HTML . you can check it by inspecting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `align-center: center`, like this:

```html
.elementor-element-acf3e44{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

But height of the parent div must be large than 0. thanks

Comment: i still have the same problem. it didn't work

Comment: Excuse me, please send your html and css code. I couldn't understand enough.

Comment: It's done now. i have fix it with flex-grow and put the margin left and right to auto . thank you so much